# How can I start playing the audio track of a AVPlayer in the background?

Tags: avplayer, avplayerlayer

How do you play another item when the one playing is finished (think playlist...)

I want to be able to create a new AVPlayerLayer and attach a player to it and start it in the background (ie. audio only).

Thanks

I know I can keep the audio of a streaming video in the background by doing self?.playerLayer?.player = nil when leaving the foreground. That is not what I am asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip a playerLayer if you like. AVPlayerLayer is only a visual class that uses an AVPlayer.

player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:theURL];

[player play];

or

[yourPlayerLayer.player play]

Bob's your auntie